# Import XML into SQL Server 2005 data not imported

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, import

I have a table titled Code, with two fields, ID and Code.

I have an XML file:

```
 <DataSet>
   <scan>
     <ID>4</ID>
     <Code>420</Code>
   </scan>
   <scan>
     <ID>5</ID>
     <Code>420</Code>
   </scan>
   <scan>
     <ID>6</ID>
     <Code>420</Code>
   </scan>
   <scan>
     <ID>4</ID>
     <Code>420</Code>
   </scan>
   <scan>
     <ID>5</ID>
     <Code>420</Code>
   </scan>
  </DataSet>
```

and am using this

```
 INSERT INTO code (id,code) 
 SELECT X.scan.query('id').value('.','INT'),
   X.scan.query('code').value('.','VARCHAR(30)')
 FROM ( 
 SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
 FROM OPENROWSET(
      BULK 'C:\dataimport.xml',
      SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
       ) AS T(x)
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('dataset/scan') AS X(scan);
```

The query runs without error, but no data is inserted into the Code table. 
I can't see what I'm missing.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML in SQL Server is case sensitive.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO code (id,code)
SELECT X.scan.query('ID').value('.','INT'),
       X.scan.query('Code').value('.','VARCHAR(30)')
FROM ( 
SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'C:\dataimport.xml',
    SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
      ) AS T(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('DataSet/scan') AS X(scan);
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance and help. Know I know what to look for when I get the same result.

Comment: Is it only case sensitive in the .nodes( ) portion of the query? I tested the case sensitivity in other areas and the case didn't seem to matter. I changed scan.query to Scan.query and it worked okay. I take it the .nodes('DataSet/scan') need to match the case of the nodes in the XML. Is that correct? Thanks

Comment: It's the xPath expressions that are case sensitive. The strings you use in nodes, query and value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the native SQL Server 2005 XML support - something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @input XML

SELECT @input = CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\dataimport.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)

INSERT INTO Code(ID, Code)
   SELECT 
       Scan.value('(ID)[1]', 'int'),
       Scan.value('(Code)[1]', 'varchar(30)')
   FROM @input.nodes('/DataSet/scan') AS Tbl(Scan)
```

Comment: You fixed the issue but failed to mention what the problem was. +1 for a nicer looking and probably better performing query.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: I assume it's because the XPath expression `.nodes('dataset/scan')` isn't paying attention to the **casing** of the string - it should be `.nodes('DataSet/scan')` as in the XML - but that's just a guess... :-)